# Replacing iframe source with main URL

Tags: html, url, iframe

I am not sure if this is possible or not... 
I am trying to replace a specific part of a URL from my iframe with a string that is part of the mainframe's URL.

i.e. I am trying to replace the iframe link to include the userID.

```
Main URL:  https://web.example.com?userID=9553c6


<iframe src="https://app.example.com?[Insert userID here]"></iframe>
```

Comment: It's possible but it depends how you're outputting the iframe tag. If you're doing it within source code, you can do this with something server-side like PHP. If you're injecting it into the DOM via JavaScript, you can do it via JS.

Comment: I am trying to do it inject it via JavaScript, but I do not know how.

Answer (score 0):

If your site where is  content under address https://web.example.com?userID=9553c6 in my opinion you can do this using eg. php

```
<body>
    <iframe src="http://example.com?user_id=<?php echo urlencode($_GET['userId']) ?>"></iframe>
</body>
```

Then variable `$_GET['userId']` will have value of `9553c6`

Or you can use only js which will be a bit harder, because you have to parse `location.search` https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_search.asp and get specific part of it. Of course this value of param `userId` will be from main site.

Direct solution

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <style>
            iframe {
                width: 100%;
                height: 1000px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="http://fotokrajobrazy.warmia.pl/galeria/fota.php?nr=1004"></iframe>
    </body>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            var res = location.search.match(/userId\=(\w+)/);
            var fr = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
            fr.setAttribute('src', fr.getAttribute('src').replace(/(nr\=)\d+/, '$1'+res[1]));
        };
    </script>
</html>
```

You can then edit main url like this:
http://127.0.0.1/stack.html?userId=1003
and
http://127.0.0.1/stack.html?userId=1002
etc. and the url of iframe will change too.

Answer (score 0):

You need some simple string-hangling.

You say you're injecting the frame via JavaScript, so I'll suppose your code looks something like this.

```
let
ifr = document.createElement('iframe'),
src = 'some/url/here?user={user-id}',
user_id = '123456';
src = src.replace('{user-id}', user_id)
;
document.body.appendChild(ifr);
```

The key line is the one with `.replace()` - that's where we replace the placeholder with the actual value.